# SQL to select rows that match a URL with wildcard

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, regex, linq

I have a table in the db with one column containing a URL like http://example.com/users/*/profile

I am given a URL (like http://example.com/users/234/profile) and want to select all the rows in the db that match the url (in this case * is a wildcard).

I was thinking of using Regex to do this, by replacing the * with regex for any character. But am unsure as to what the SQL or LINQ code should be for the selection.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I am missing something obvious, this should just require a simple [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) query.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE URL LIKE 'http://example.com/users/%/'
```

Regex is overkill and tricky in SQL queries.

Note: The % character is the equivalent of the * wildcard in SQL expressions.

If you want to use LINQ and are only working against SQL Server, you can use this syntax:

```
var results =
        from yt in YourTable
        where SqlMethods.Like(yt.URL, "http://example.com/users/%/")
        select yt;
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that in linq? Seems they only have startswith, contains, etc...

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as doing a like, but replacing the * character by the % character since it's the wildcard character used by T-SQL (I am assuming you are on SQL Server since this is C# and Linq related)

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE @TheUrlIWantToMatch LIKE REPLACE(URL, '*', '%')
```

Comment: Like doesn't work that way. You can't have a wildcard in the expression before the LIKE keyword.

Comment: Oops I put them in the wrong order. I edited it thanks for pointing that out